# Dealing with lots of strftime in Python

Tags: python, string, datetime

I have code that deals with dates a **lot**. I have a small helper function when reading these dates in from a string:

```
def date(iso_date_string, date_format='%Y-%m-%d'):
    """
    Convenience function to make a date.
    """
    return datetime.strptime(iso_date_string, date_format)
```

When I come to write these out I seem to be writing:

```
date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

all over my code. Not only is this becoming a pain, but lots of reuse of the same code suggests to me factorisation for better maintainability and clarity.

So, what is the easiest and most Pythonic way to do this:

- Should I wrap Python's `datetime` within my own class? This seems non-Pythonic and a bit nasty.
- Should I monkey patch `datetime` somehow? Also seems very nasty.
- Some other way...?

Any help/ideas with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you have a reverse function `date -> iso_date_string`? Alternatively, could you use the standard `datetime.__str__` internally and leave the output formatting to whatever the user selects?

Comment: A helper function (taking a date object and returning a string) seems like the most straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward way would be to use a helper function symmetric to the `date` you already have:

```
def datestr(date_value, date_format='%Y-%m-%d'):
   return date_value.strftime(date_format)
```

Then formatting a date can be done in a a simple function call like `datestr(d)`.

Having a pair of helper functions to convert to/from a string is a simple an clear way to wrap your specific functionality. I don't think making things more complicated and error prone by monkey patching/... would gain anything.

If you have many such helper functions that work on dates it might be useful to move them to a separate module, to make things more organized. If you for example create a `dateutil` module it will be quite obvious that this module contains helper function that work on dates.

Comment: Although probably don't call your helper module `dateutil`, because [that already exists](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil)

Answer (score 1):

strftime doesnt work with dates <1900. Make sure this is not a problem in your app. I wrote code for a project that had strftime all over the place, and when we needed to deal with dates before 1900 we had to make a custom function and replace those strftime calls with it. You can see how I fixed it here (*fixed_strftime* function): https://github.com/carolinux/TimeManager/blob/860308e1448517923ef4b6dcb6a73cbd2417c599/time_util.py

Given how broken datetime is, if I wanted to do this over again and had complete control of the program, I would use the Delorean (http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library for time handling. Wrapping datetime in your own class is not nasty at all, it's a way to deal with the problems Python has with time handling, just don't roll your own, since it has been done already.

Comment: Thanks for the point out to Delorean. It's probably overkill for what I need but very useful nonetheless.

Comment: You're welcome. More people should know about this library. :)

Comment: @user383105: don't trust `Delorean` blindly. [Its author does not know (or pretends to) the difference between `datetime.now()` and `datetime.now(timezone_object)`](https://github.com/myusuf3/delorean/pull/46)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a better name: `date_object = from_iso_date(string)`:

```
from datetime import date

def from_iso_date(string):
    """'%Y-%m-%d' string -> date object."""
    return date(*map(int, string.split("-")))
```

and in reverse `string = date_object.isoformat()`.